# Avoiding getting a substring?

Tags: c++, string

I have a situation where I have a std::string, and I only need characters x to x + y, and I think it would speed it up quite a bit if I instead could somehow do (char*)&string[x], but the problem is all my functions expect a NULL terminated string.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any profiling to make sure that creating substrings is a major performance issue for your application?

Comment: Please, why is everyone always trying to optimize the STL? That's the compilers' job.

Comment: I have a low budget Dell with a Core i7. SiSoft Sandra reports a memory bandwidth of 17GB/s. How long can it take to copy a substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing nice can be done. The only trick I can think of is temporarily setting `s[x+y+1]` to 0, pass `&s[x]`, then restore the character. But you should resort to this ONLY if you are sure this will reasonably boost the performance and that boost is necessary

Answer (score 1):

nothing (if the string you need is in the middle). the speed difference will be utterly trivial unless its being done A LOT (several millions)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
string.c_str() + x;
```

This assumes your function takes a `const char *`

If you need actual 0-termination, you'll have to copy.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice here.  You can't create a null-terminated substring without copying or modifying the original string.

You say you "think it would speed it up".  Have you measured?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* overwrite `&string[x+y+1]` with a NUL, and pass `&string[x]` to your functions. If you're going to need the whole string again afterward, you can save it for the duration, and restore it when needed.